# new Texture(Gdx.files.absolute(string)); is giving vague output

Tags: android, libgdx

i am taking a picutre from camera and crop the image for face and than saved that cropped image.
After than i am using the path of that saved image i am loading it as a texture of LibGdx.

problem is that for Android version higher or equivalent to 4.0.4 instead of displaying the cropped image it is showing one of the sprite sheet that is in assets folder.

Comment: Are you catching `GdxRuntimeException` anywhere?  The actual texture loading won't happen immediately, so if there are problems reading the file, they may happen later.  You can try manually creating a `Pixmap` from the file and creating a `Texture` via the Pixmap to get more visibility into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is for loading the texture but the texture is loaded a little while after the execution of the statement as it is done in a separate thread.

since you have the cropped image, don't save it to file just directly convert it to texture using the Pixmap class.

the above answer in the comment. is also the same thing.